# Wireless connection dies when cordless phone rings?

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

I have a Cisco Linksys wireless N gigabit router, model number WRT310N that I'm using as a wireless ACCESS POINT in my home network. It usually works fine, however, whenever my 2.4 GHz cordless house phone rings the WiFi connections on all the computers drop. They restart again when the phone call ends.

I've read somewhere about changing the 'channel' or something on the router, but I can't seem to find exactly how to do it on the router setup and I'm scared of doing the wrong thing in case I break something.

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem? It's getting increasingly frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the channel in the web interface of your router. Read your router documentation for details. Don't be afraid to change it, you can't brake anything.

However, cordless phones communicate via spread-spectrum in the same frequency ranges as WLAN, so if your phone causes interference on one channel, it may also cause interference on other channels. It also may be broken and cause unintended interference, so another options is to buy a new cordless base station and/or phones.